# Trying to resolve a SQL Query issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I’ve this 2 below SQL Queries which only differs in date-time criteria, one will return data and other will not… Can someone please help…?

Query which returns data –

```
SELECT *
FROM CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT,
  CA_ENCOUNTER_REF TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER,
  (SELECT DISTINCT TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.ENCOUNTER_ID,
    TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_NAME
  FROM CA_CAPM_ENCOUNTER_ATTR TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES,
    CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT
  WHERE (CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM BETWEEN TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_BEGIN_DTTM AND NVL(TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_END_DTTM,SYSDATE)
  OR NVL(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.COMPLETE_DTTM,SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_BEGIN_DTTM AND NVL(TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_END_DTTM,SYSDATE)
  OR TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_BEGIN_DTTM BETWEEN CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM AND NVL(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.COMPLETE_DTTM,SYSDATE))
  AND CAST(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM AS DATE) BETWEEN '30-06-2016 12:00:00' AND **'30-06-2016 23:59:00'**
  ) PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES
WHERE CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.ENCOUNTER_ID      = TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_ID
AND TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_ID  = PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.ENCOUNTER_ID(+)
AND TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER.PATIENT_ID <> '0'
AND CAST(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM AS DATE) BETWEEN '30-06-2016 12:00:00' AND **'30-06-2016 23:59:00'**;
```

Query which doesn’t return data -

```
SELECT *
FROM CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT,
  CA_ENCOUNTER_REF TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER,
  (SELECT DISTINCT TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.ENCOUNTER_ID,
    TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.ATTRIBUTE_NAME
  FROM CA_CAPM_ENCOUNTER_ATTR TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES,
    CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT
  WHERE (CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM BETWEEN TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_BEGIN_DTTM AND NVL(TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_END_DTTM,SYSDATE)
  OR NVL(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.COMPLETE_DTTM,SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_BEGIN_DTTM AND NVL(TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_END_DTTM,SYSDATE)
  OR TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.EFF_BEGIN_DTTM BETWEEN CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM AND NVL(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.COMPLETE_DTTM,SYSDATE))
  AND CAST(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM AS DATE) BETWEEN '30-06-2016 12:00:00' AND **'01-07-2016 23:59:00'** –Running for longer time frame
  ) PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES
WHERE CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.ENCOUNTER_ID      = TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_ID
AND TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_ID  = PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES.ENCOUNTER_ID(+)
AND TRANSPORT_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER.PATIENT_ID <> '0'
AND CAST(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM AS DATE) BETWEEN '30-06-2016 12:00:00' AND **'01-07-2016 23:59:00'**;
```

Comment: (i) I trust, there are no side effects (concurrent updates/deletes...). (ii) Did you verify, the inner `SELECT` to return data? (iii) Did you check, whether an inner join has the same issue? (iv) Did you consider to make your date conversion explicit? (It looks now like comparing twelve against 36 hours' worth of data.) (v) What does **CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM** data look like, and what are your **NLS_LANG** settings? (vi) Do you really (intend to) start with end of June and extend into July - or the other way around? (vii) Are you just not getting any data or an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of strings to represent the date-time values. If we run `DUMP()` on your strings we get this:

```
SQL> select dump('30-06-2016 12:00:00') as dt 
  2  from dual
  3  /

DT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=19: 51,48,45,48,54,45,50,48,49,54,32,49,50,58,48,48,58,48,48

SQL>
```

`Typ=96` means it's [a CHAR value](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr06002.htm#SQLQR959) (a date would be `Typ=12`). So Oracle will apply character semantics to the operation. In effect this ...

```
x BETWEEN '30-06-2016 12:00:00' AND '01-07-2016 23:59:00'
```

... evaluates to ...

```
'30' >= '30' AND '30' <= '01'
```

... which is clearly nonsense.

What you need to do is use explicit casts with a format mask:

```
BETWEEN to_date('30-06-2016 12:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
    AND to_date('01-07-2016 23:59:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Yep. If OP's query had written dates as `'2016-07-01 23:59:00'`, the query would have a fighting chance of comparing them as strings and getting the right result. Comparing two strings, it will look character by character left to right to determine which string is greater. It doesn't consider the "meaning" of a string. The right solution (I agree with the answer, just restating it in different words) is to convert all strings to `DATE` type to compare them.

Comment: ISO date literal `date '2016-07-01 23:59:00'` can be used instead of `to_char` function, it is shorter a bit.

Comment: @APC, @Peter M: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements002.htm suggests "When comparing a character value with a DATE value, Oracle converts the character data to DATE." So, why does `CAST(CA_CLN_CAPM_TRANSPORT.SCHEDULED_DTTM AS DATE)` not bring **DATE** comparison semantics to the task?

Comment: @Abecee, hard to say (and may be dependent on OP's locale settings?) Maybe that CAST(... as DATE) is failing because it doesn't find the format it expects? It may be flaky because the format isn't written explicitly. Just from observation, I would guess the query is comparing as string. And OP can easily test for that behavior now that we have mentioned it.

Comment: the inner select works just fine without using to_date, whereas on the outer query when i used to_date and specified the format mentioned by @APC the query works just fine and returns me data...i'm creating a report using Business Objects and to hard code the date format i'll have to create a custom filter which i'm trying to avoid. FYI -SCHEDULED_DTTM is of timestamp datatype. Is there any other way to tweak the SQL without mentioning the to_date..

Comment: I removed CAST AS Date in my BO Universe and the query is working fine ..thank you guys for all the help..